# Is there still a need for css normalize or reset, so the app renders the same across different devices?

Tags: css, onsen-ui, normalize-css

I'm developing front end interface for mobile apps. 
Is there still a need for CSS Normalize or Reset, so the app renders the same across different mobile devices?

Comment: You don't need to do anything manually as far as I know. It should be displayed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, however the css support is different on different systems. I can recommend this site http://caniuse.com/ .